# How to extract features with specific coordinates from a ShapeFile?

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinates, ogr2ogr, filter

I would like to extract a number of features from a ShapeFile which match with **specific latitude/longitude values**.  I am interested if/how this can be done with QGIS and ogr2ogr. The output should be a ShapeFile as well; for QGIS a layer is sufficient.

I assume the command for ogr2ogr could be something like:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -where "Y = 40.752459 AND X = -73.983521" output.shp input.shp
```

However I am having difficulties finding out what the attributes for lat/lon are named.

*Optional*: Also, is there an option for a fuzzy query where I can configure a radius around the coordinates?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. with QGIS 1.9.0 via [ubuntugis-nightly](http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly) and GDAL 1.10.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using a single coordinate pair for accuracy reasons. For the fuzzy query, you can better create a buffer around that point.

Using QGIS, you can create points with the `Numerical Digitize` Plugin by coordinates, then create a buffer circle around the point with `Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Buffer(s)`, and clip the shapefile layer to that buffer layer.

Comment: Sounds good. But how can I select a coordinate by typing in the latitude/longitude values?

Comment: The Numerical Digitize Plugin allows entering coordinates in a simple way.

Comment: I extracted [NumericalDigitize 0.1.4](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/numericalDigitize/) into `.qgis2/python/plugins`. It appears in the plugins list however it **cannot be activated** for QGIS 1.9.0. -- *"This plugin is incompatible with this version of QGIS.
Plugin designed for QGIS 1.5 - 1.99"*

Comment: I managed to activate NumericalDigitize 0.1.4. by editing the version tag in `metadata.txt` and (optionally) `__init.py__`. It set `qgisMinimumVersion=2.0`. QGIS must be restarted to reload the modified plugin.

Comment: It worked for me in QGIS 1.8.0. You stumbled on the new plugin policy, which leads to problems until QGIS 2.0 is finally released.

Answer (score 1):

An early solution with a PostGIS database (local installation).

If you want a radius you can use the `ST_buffer` function.
2 commands with ogr2ogr allow you to obtain your output shapefile :

1 -- load into PostGIS :

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" \
    PG:"host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres dbname=mydb password=mypwd" \
    input.shp -nln newtablename -nlt geometry -overwrite
```

2 -- execute query and export result with a radius --> `st_buffer()  500` is the radius :

```
ogr2ogr -f  "Esri Shapefile" output.shp -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -s_srs "EPSG:4326" \
    PG:"host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres dbname=mydb password=mypwd" \
    -sql "select id_1, id_1 as name_field, id_1 as value_1_field, wkb_geometry \
    from newtablename, ( select  'id_x' as id, \
    setsrid(ST_buffer(ST_MakePoint(40.752459 , -73.98352),500),4326) as geom ) \
    as mypoint_with_radius where \
    st_intersects(newtablename.wkb_geometry, mypoint_with_radius.geom)" \
    PGCLIENTENCODING=LATIN1
```

I work on Windows 7 with [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org) but I can't test it on another machine.
I hope it will be useful ...